# Solve DE: $y'' + 4y = 2t$ with Fourier Series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

Consider the differential equation
$$ y'' + 4y = \cases{2t & \text{if }0\le t \le \pi,\\0 & \text{otherwise},}$$
with initial conditions $y(0)=0,y'(0)=1$. I want to solve this via Fourier Series. The homogeneous problem is solved by $A\cos 2t + B\sin2t$. Also, let $f(t)=2t$. Its Fourier series (extending $f(t)$ periodically) is:

$$f(t) = \frac{\pi}{4} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(-\frac2n\right)\sin 2nt.$$

Suppose that $\displaystyle y_\text{p} = c_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n\sin 2nt$ is a particular solution of the differential equation. Then it is obvious that $c_0=\pi/4$ and:
$$-\sum_{n=1}^\infty 4n^2c_n\sin 2nt + 4\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n\sin 2nt = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(-\frac2n\right)\sin 2nt.$$

Thus $c_n(1-n^2) = -\frac{1}{2n}$, which doesn't hold for $n=1$. How can I deal with this problem? Note that the term $\sin2(1)t$ is in the homogeneous solution (is this relevant to the problem at $n=1$?). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why should you have a periodic solution when the forcing is not periodic? Indeed the solution to your problem is not periodic.

Comment: @Ian the forcing can be periodic if one extends periodically the function as I did. The important thing is that one can select the domain $[0,\pi]$, and say that the solution found with Fourier Series is valid in that domain. If you change $4$ (next to $t$) by any non-integer number then the solution is well behaved and exists using Fourier Series

Comment: Wait, are you extending the forcing periodically on the whole line, considering the non-periodic problem on the whole line, or just considering the problem on $[0,\pi]$?

Comment: @Ian I have to extend the forcing periodically on the whole line and consider the solution only on $[0,\pi]$

Comment: @VladimirVargas But that's an entirely different problem, as then you've lost any information about $f$ that comes from the fact that it is supported on $[0,\pi]$. Rather than Fourier series, a Fourier transform seems more naturally suited to this problem.

Comment: @GyuEunLee I don't follow why this shouldn't work. I take the function $f$ and extend it periodically. Its Fourier series will tell me the behaviour of $f$ in the interval I'm interested in.

Comment: Sure. It won't, however, tell you the behavior of $y$. Note that if $y$ is periodic, then $y'' + 4y$ is necessarily also periodic. Yet the original inhomogeneous term, $g(x) = 2x$ on $[0,\pi]$ and $0$ elsewhere, is not periodic. So no periodic function can hope to solve the original ODE. Your approach only works if the inhomogeneous term is already equal to the periodization $f$ you are attempting to use.

Comment: @GyuEunLee So, just to be sure, no periodic function will solve the ODE even on the interval $[0,\pi]$?

Comment: Oh, there's a periodic solution to the ODE *if the domain of $y$ and the forcing term is restricted to $[0,\pi]$.* But there is no periodic solution valid on $(-\infty,\infty)$ for this problem. Also, since the periodization of $2x$ on $[0,\pi]$ to $(-\infty,\infty)$ is discontinuous, you'll see some poor convergence properties of the Fourier series near the endpoints (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon).

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to say: if we restrict the problem to that interval then there should be a solution... but I'm having trouble with that $n=1$ term. @GyuEunLee